# main() not called in non concurrent NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

When creating an NSOperation and putting it into an NSOperationQueue, I never see main() being called. Only start() is getting called. I'm not doing anything fancy, really. As a simple test, I wrote this:

```
NSOperationQueue *testOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
MyTestOperation *testOperation = [[MyTestOperation alloc] init];
[testOperationQueue addOperation:testOperation];
```

in MyTestOperation.m:

```
- (void)main
{
  NSLog(@"testing if main is getting called");
}

- (void)start
{
  NSLog(@"testing if start is getting called");
}
```

MyTestOperation.h looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyTestOperation : NSOperation

@end
```

Am I missing something obvious?

[Edit Note: I actually meant non concurrent, not concurrent (as written in the previous title).]

Comment: What does the "`@interface`" .h file for "`MyTestOperation`" look like?

Comment: I've included the MyTestOperation.h above.

Answer (score 7):

I played around with your code and noticed that if I commented out your `start` method entirely, the `main` method would run. After reading the documentation for `start` more closely, I found this line:

> The default implementation of this method updates the execution state of the operation and calls the receiver’s `main` method.

Thus, by overriding `start` with an implementation that didn't call `main`, you effectively short-circuited the operation and never allowed it to actually begin working! Therefore, you either need to explicitly call `main` within your `start` method, or you need to eliminate `start` all-together if you're not actually using it to do setup/update execution state/etc.

Comment: Yea. I tried the same and just overwrote main (left start() out) and now main is called. Thanks for the clarification!